# Is there a way to search a .txt file for lines containing two user input variables and then print the lines in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I have this .txt file called "Search_this_file.txt" which contains the following information:

```
12:00:00 AM First_Name Last_Name
01:00:00 AM First_Name1 Last_Name2
...
01:00:00 PM First_Name13 Last_Name13
...
11:00:00 PM First_Name23 Last_Name23
```

I'm trying to write a bash script that will scan the information in "Search_this_file.txt" line-by-line and only print out the lines that match two user input variables. In my case, I'm asking the user to input the time (eg. "12:00:00") and whether it's AM or PM. So, if someone types in "01:00:00" for time and "PM" for AM/PM, the bash script will run and print "01:00:00 PM First_Name13 Last_Name13" in the Command Line Terminal.

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash/

read -p "Enter time in HH:MM:SS format " TIME
read -p "AM or PM? " AMPM

echo -e | grep -Fiw '$TIME' Search_this_file.txt | 
grep -Fiw "$AMPM"
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is your question?  What do the commands produce now, and how does it differ from what you want?  Read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there friend.

Just a single change you need to do:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter time in HH:MM:SS format " TIME
read -p "AM or PM? " AMPM

echo -e | grep -Fiw "$TIME" Search_this_file.txt | 
grep -Fiw "$AMPM"
```

Putting a single quote in Linux does not treat it as a variable.

Additionally, if you want a little better code you can refer below:

```
#!/bin/bash

 read -p "Enter time in HH:MM:SS format " TIME
 read -p "AM or PM? " AMPM

  while read line
  do 
  if [[$line == *"$TIME $AMPM"*]]; then
      echo $line
  fi
  done < your input file.txt
```

Just adds more reliability to the code. Hope this helps.